# How to test angular code that relies on global variables in karma?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

How do I test angular code in karma that depends on a global variable? Yes, I know, global vars are a **really bad idea**, but sometimes they exist due to other code or dependencies.

E.g. if I depend on a global var called `G`, I have fully isolated it to a single file that sets it for all other parts of the app and provides it as a service, but I still need to test my angular code for when it is or is not set.

```
describe('G is not set',function (){
  beforeEach(function(){
    // need to set a global var G here
  });
});
describe('G is set',function (){
  beforeEach(function(){
    // need to set a global var G here
  });
});
```

The code itself might be a simple

```
var ret = typeof(G) === "undefined" ? {} : G;
```

And then I can pass ret on which is used by the module.

But how do I set it in karma?

Answer (score 3):

So the answer turns out to be in 2 parts.

1. In the tester: karma supports a global variable, just set it in the test file. If using browserify, use `global.G = "ABC"` (or whatever you want to set it to.
2. In the app itself. See below.

In the app itself, if the file references the global var, it will be read once at load time, as it should. So I converted it to a function. Instead of having the other areas of the app inject a service, e.g. `Greader`, and then doing

```
if (Greader.info === "1") {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

I converted Greader.info to a function (or use getters, if you prefer), which reads the global var real time:

```
if (Greader.info() === "1") {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

And thus Greader.info looks like (simplified):

```
Greader = function() {return (typeof(G) === "undefined" ? {} : G);};
```

In other words, it reads it in real time. Then my tests can easily set it:

```
describe('G is not set',function (){
  beforeEach(function(){
    global.G = null;
  });
});
describe('G is set',function (){
  beforeEach(function(){
    global.G = "ABC";
  });
});
```